# Размер кнопок для разных размеров экранов

Tags: android

Как правильно задать размер кнопкам для разных экранов? Нужно ли для этого несколько создавать ресурсов "dimens" для разного разрешения?
Пример:
values-sw360dp
values-sw480dp
values-sw600dp
....и.т.д

И если нужно это делать, то какие размеры нужно вписывать?
Допустим мы знает что стандартный размер для кнопки 48 dp.

Comment: смотря какого результата вы пытаетесь достич. Если хотите, чтобы кнопки были однинакового размера *физически* (в милиметрах) на всех экранах, то нужно задавать только один размер, например просто `48dp`. Если же они должны изменять свой физический размер в зависимости от параметров дисплея, то ятрудитесь рассказать ,как именно,

Comment: Правильным будет тот вариант, который сделает интерфейс адекватным на всех экранах. По вашей щедрой постановке вопроса можно лишь посоветовать тестировать приложение на всех экранах подряд и методом тыка подгонять размеры кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

Просто делайте свою разметку в dp. Тк это пиксели, независимые от плотности. Следовательно, для того , чтобы приложение выглядело одинаково на разных экранах , вы должны описать все в dp,в противном случае, создавать альтернативные разметки . Тут можно почитать про единицы измерения в Android . [Ссылка](http://www.pandacoder.com/android_dimension_px_sp_dp/)